# OpenERP - how model selection influences a view

Tags: xml, odoo

I am trying to create brand new view, without inheriting from any existing views. There is a problem I think the reason is I use model=mrp.bom in my XML and it wiped out the form elements in Bill of Materials detail form view showing only one link. Here is XML, I think I have done something wrong there.

```
<record id="bom_where_use_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">bom.where.use.form</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="product_tmpl_id" on_change="onchange_product_tmpl_id(product_tmpl_id, 0, context)"/> 
            </field>         
         </record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is defining a view for `mrp.bom` with higher priority than the existing views. That's why your view is used to show the `mrp.bom` objects.

To give a lower priority to your view try the following:

```
<record id="bom_where_use_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">bom.where.use.form</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="99"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="product_tmpl_id"
               on_change="onchange_product_tmpl_id(product_tmpl_id,
                                                   0, context)"/> 
    </field>         
 </record>
```

Pay attention to the

```
<field name="priority" eval="99"/>
```

row.